# SQL запрос на выборку

Tags: sql

Имеются таблицы такого вида:
[image: диаграмма с таблицами]

Каким образом выбрать новости `NEWS` по конкретным нескольки тегам `TAGS`?
Вот мой нерабочий вариант:

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.news_id, news.CREATION_DATE, news.MODIFICATION_DATE, news.FULL_TEXT, news.TITLE, news.SHORT_TEXT
    FROM
      news
      INNER JOIN
      news_tags
        ON news.news_id = news_tags.news_id
        WHERE news_tags.TAG_ID = 1 AND news_tags.TAG_ID = 3;
```

Comment: Замените в условии `AND` на `OR`. А еще лучше, на `IN (1,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочее решение вопроса:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  news.news_id,
  news.CREATION_DATE,
  news.MODIFICATION_DATE,
  news.FULL_TEXT,
  news.TITLE,
  news.SHORT_TEXT
FROM news
INNER JOIN news_tags
  ON news.news_id = news_tags.news_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM news_tags
              WHERE news_id = news.news_id
              AND tag_id = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM news_tags
            WHERE news_id = news.news_id
            AND tag_id = 3);
```

Comment: На мой взгляд решение с оператором IN намного проще, понятнее и производительнее, чем несколько подзапросов. В случае с оператором IN вам остается только собрать строку со списком идентификаторов тэгов. Учитывая то, что вы собираете запрос в Java-приложении, составить такую строку не составит труда. Решение с IN более производительно (в случае наличия скажем 10+ тэгов), более компактно, и немного легче в исполнении чем собирать ваши подзапросы. В любом случае - это ваша задача, и вам решать какое решение использовать :) Рад что хоть чем-то помог.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде всё просто же:

```
select dstinct nt.news_id
from news_tag nt
where nt.tag_id in (1, 3)
```

Либо подготовь пул идентификаторов искомых тэгов, либо ищи по именам. Тогда тебе нужно будет сделать немного по другому:

```
select dstinct nt.news_id
from news_tag nt
left join tags t on t.tag_id = nt.tag_id
where t.tag_name in ('First tag', 'Second tag')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но данный вариант не совсем мне подходит, дело в том, что запрос нужно составлять каждый раз новый, за что отвечает java-приложение, а данную конструкцию довольно неудобно модифицировать